# EMV transaction apple/google pay

Tags: android, transactions, wallet, emv, contactless-smartcard

I need to write a program for making contactless transactions that will support both payment with a physical EMV credit card chip, and payment with Google Pay or Apple Pay,
I have to treat each transaction **differently** and currently I have no way to differentiate between these types of transactions because they are both cataloged under "Contactless"

What is the earliest possible indication that I have from the moment the card is recognized until I can tell what type of transaction it is?

Is there a unique AIP for Google or Apple Pay transactions?
I saw that there is an option through tag 82 to see if a certain bit is on, but I didn't understand how I could check....
What other ways do I have to get the indication?

I tried to look for a unique parameter that differentiates between the types of transactions, I tried to look for whether there are unique tags but I saw that it varies between each brand and it was not so clear to me,
I saw that it was possible through tag 82, but I didn't understand exactly how

Comment: Have you checked tag 9F19 during READ RECORD ? This should give you token requestor ID.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a reliable way to do this currently.  Tag 9F19 can be used to obtain a tokenization requestor Id, which will be unique per wallet and scheme combo.  This can be used to determine the wallet type; However the tag is optional, and there are a lot of wallet implementations that don't have this tag. So there is a fair chance that you can't tell if it is Android Pay, Apple Pay or a Physical card.